Example of a discrete metric on R that attains four different values
As per the title, I am asked to produce an example for the reals. My solution involves discretizing the euclidean metric $d(x, y) =|x-y|$, such that:
$\rho(x, y) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{llll}
              0 & \text{if } x = y \\
              1 & \text{if } 0 < d(x,y) \leq 1 \\
              2 & \text{if } 1 < d(x,y) \leq 2 \\
              3 & \text{if } 2 < d(x,y) \\
        \end{array} 
        \right. $
From what I understand, $\rho$ should be a metric since it is obtained from $d$, which we know is a metric. Is there any fault in this solution? Any feedback is appreciated!

I'm not sure what you mean with the sentence "$\rho$ should be a metric since it is obtained from $d$, which we know is a metric." If you are not careful about the choice of values, this can go wrong, like if you choose "$1000$ if $1 < d(x,y) \le 2$". You may be aware of that, but it isn't clear from what you wrote. To make the proof easier, I suggest using values that automatically fulfill the triangle inequality , like $1, 1.1, 1.2$ instead of $1,2,3$. That makes it unnecessary to check the exact conditions as @Especially Time need to do in his answer.

Yes, this looks good. To verify it's a metric you need to check that for distinct $x,y,z$ we have $\rho(x,z)\leq \rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)$. Since the RHS is at least $2$, the only case that can go wrong is when $\rho(x,z)=3$, but then $d(x,y)+d(y,z)\geq d(x,z)>2$ so at least one of $\rho(x,y)$ and $\rho(y,z)$ is $2$.
